# Identity for Power Series and Binomial Coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

This question concerns a combinatorial identity obeyed by power series coefficients.  Throughout we let $[x^{M}]\{\phi(x)\}$ denote the coefficient of $x^{M}$ in a power series $\phi(x)$.

Let $k$ be a positive integer, and consider the function $F(k,x)$ defined as the following power series in $x$:

\begin{equation}
F(k,x)=\sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{s-1}}{s^{2}}\binom{s \ k}{s+1}(s+1)\ x^{s}.
\end{equation}

I am interested in the series coefficients of the function $\exp(N F (k,x))$ for positive integer $N.$

Through comparison of various formulas that arose in a research project, I have been lead to the following identity for the case $N=M+1$:

\begin{equation}
[x^{M}]\{e^{(M+1)F(k,x)}\}= \frac{k(M+1)}{k+(k-1)M}\binom{(k-1)^{2}M+k(k-1)}{M}~.
\end{equation}

Although I am convinced that this identity is true, I have no idea how to demonstrate it, nor do I have any idea why this power series coefficient has such a simple expression. Thus, my main question is how can this identity be motivated and proven ?

More generally, can we determine the coefficient $[x^{M}]\{e^{N F(k,x)}\}?$

I am also interested in a generalization which depends on an additional positive integer $j$.  Specifically, set
\begin{equation}
F(k,j,x)=\sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{s-1}}{s^{2}}\binom{s \ k}{s\ j+1}(s\ j+1)\ x^{s}~.
\end{equation}
The previous function is recovered for the special case $j=1.$

Can the coefficients $[x^{M}]\{e^{NF(k,j,x)}\}$ be similarly determined?

Comment: What's the connection with representation theory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems that a general formula for the $x^M$ coefficient of $\exp NF(k,x)$ is
$$
\frac{N}{M} (k^2-k) \left( {(k^2-k) N - (k-1) M - 1 \atop M-1} \right),
$$
which agrees with your formula when $N=M+1$.  This should follow from
an explicit formula for $dF(k,x)/dx$ as a degree-$k$ algebraic function of $x$
that's closely related with the inverse function of $y(1-y)^{k-1}$, for which
there's a closed-form power series expansion of $y^\beta$ for all $\beta$;
see for instance 
[these](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/catalan.pdf)
[two](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/catalan2.pdf)
"one-page papers"
[on my
math webpage](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/index.html#papers).

Comment: Thanks Noam!  I will look into this idea.  Does anything similar work in the case j>1?

Comment: You're welcome.  For other $j$ there doesn't seem to be such a nice formula, except in the roughly-complementary
case of $j=k-1$.  Otherwise the power-series coefficients,
written as polynomials in $N$, are generally irreducible once you
remove the factor of $N$.  (For $j=1$ they factor completely,
which soon led me to surmise the formula above.)

Answer (score 9):

To elaborate on Noam's answer, 
$$F(k, y(y+1)^{k-1}) = k(k-1)\log(1+y),$$ as can be proved by Lagrange inversion or in other ways, as in Noam's papers. So if $G(k, x) = e^{F(k,x)}$ then
$$G(k, y(y+1)^{k-1})=(1+y)^{k(k-1)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for providing the explicit formula Ira!  That helps tremendously in making the problem more concrete.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathscr{B}_t(z)$ be a **generalized binomial
series**
$$\mathscr{B}_t(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{tk+1\choose k}
\dfrac{1}{tk+1}z^k.$$ The answer follows from these two
formulae
\begin{gather}
\tag{1}\mathscr{B}_t^r(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{tk+r\choose k}
\dfrac{r}{tk+r}z^k,\\
\tag{2}\log\mathscr{B}_t(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{t k\choose
k}\frac{z^k}{tk}
\end{gather}
because
$$F(k,x)=k(1-k)\log\mathscr{B}_k(-x)=k(k-1)\log\mathscr{B}_{1-k}(x).$$

You can find (1) (and some other formulae) in (see Ch.5.4) *Graham, R.
L.; Knuth, D. E. & Patashnik, O. Concrete mathematics. Addison-Wesley Publishing
Company, 1994.*

Formula (2) follows from calculations
performed in *Bizley, M. Derivation of a new formula for the
number of minimal lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(k m, k
n)$ having just $t$ contacts with the line $m y = n x$ and
having no points above this line; and a proof of Grossman's
formula for the number of paths which may touch but do not
rise above this line. J. Inst. Actuaries 80, 55-62 (1954).*

The proof of (1) (see *Concrete Mathematics*) is also based on combinatorics of paths.
Probably it can give some tips for $j>1$.

See also [Donald Knuth's 20th Annual Christmas Tree Lecture: (3/2)-ary Trees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4AaGQIo0HY) for additional connections and for the history of
(2).

I applied these formulae in the theory of formal groups.
Can you  give us some background information about your question?

Comment: (2) can be derived from (1) by subtracting 1, dividing by $r$ and taking the limit as $r\to 0$.

Comment: Yes, and it is much more shoter than Bizley's arguments!